# Make a customized widget observable?

Tags: data-binding, eclipse-rcp, jface

I had create a simple keywords highlighting editor, it just wrap a `StyledText` widget:

```java
public class SQLSegmentEditor extends Composite {

    private StyledText st;

    public SQLSegmentEditor(Composite parent) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);
        this.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        st = new StyledText(this, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        st.addLineStyleListener(new SQLSegmentLineStyleListener());
    }

}
```

How can I make it can be used in data-binding?  I am looking for the proper way, not just one that makes it work.

**I want to observer the text content of the inner `StyledText`.**

For example : I can just add a `getStyledText` method to return the wrapped `StyledText` widget  for using it in databinding. But this will take a risk. In order to keep my editor behavior correctly,  I should keep the `StyledText` widget not visible to client code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I don't understand your argument of not exposing the wrapped widget to the client, here is a possible solution. The widget can provide a `WritableValue` that can be bound directly via databinding by the client. That means the binding goes over 3 parties: the clients target, the wrapping writable-value and the SWT source. The only drawback is that you have a direct dependency to Databinding in your widget. Here is a snippet.

```java
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.DataBindingContext;
import org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.value.WritableValue;
import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.ISWTObservableValue;
import org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.WidgetProperties;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;

public class SQLSegmentEditor extends Composite {

    private final StyledText st;

    private final WritableValue value = new WritableValue();

    public SQLSegmentEditor(Composite parent, DataBindingContext ctx) {
        super(parent, SWT.NONE);
        assert ctx != null;
        setLayout(new FillLayout());
        st = new StyledText(this, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        ISWTObservableValue swtBinding = WidgetProperties.text(SWT.Modify)
                .observe(st);
        ctx.bindValue(value, swtBinding);
    }

    public WritableValue getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

So the client code would look like:

```java
DataBindingContext ctx = new DataBindingContext();
SQLSegmentEditor sqlSegmentEditor = new SQLSegmentEditor(getParent(), ctx);
IObservableValue modelObservable = //setup my model-observable
ctx.bindValue(modelObservable, sqlSegmentEditor.getValue());
```

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I add a method to return a IObservableValue.